# Simulating a representative dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random, simulate

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
sectoral_data <- data.frame(sector=c("a","b","c","d"),share=c(0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1),avg_wage=c(400,600,800,1000))
```

where "share" is the employment share in each sector. I want simulate (I guess that's the right word) the following data frame that would represent a sample of ten individuals from that economy:

```
personal_data <- data.frame(individual=c(1:10),
                          wage=c(rep.int(400,5),rep.int(600,3),rep.int(800,1), rep.int(1000,1)),
                          sector=c(rep("a",5),rep("b",3), rep("c",1), rep("d",1))
                          )
```

Any idea of an efficient way to do this and/or if there is a built in feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sample`:

```
n <- 10

with(sectoral_data,
  data.frame(
    individual = seq_len(n),
    wage = sample(avg_wage, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = share),
    sector = sample(sector, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = share)
  ))
#   individual wage sector
#1           1  400      c
#2           2  600      c
#3           3  800      a
#4           4  800      b
#5           5  400      b
#6           6  400      a
#7           7  400      b
#8           8  600      c
#9           9  400      a
#10         10  400      c
```

Answer (score 0):

R has lot's of functions for simulating random events. In this particular case I think a multinomial random vector can be useful.

Here is an example. We say that we want to take 10 individuals, and there are 4 classes of those individuals, with distinct probabilities:

```
inds <- rmultinom(10, 1, sectoral_data$share)
inds
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
```

The result is a matrix, where within each column it indicates which individual was chosen. In order to turn this into actual indices (from 1 to 4) we call `which.max()` on each column:

```
inds <- apply(inds, 2, which.max)
inds
[1] 1 1 1 4 2 4 1 4 2 1
```

Now we can use this vector to select individuals from the original data:

```
data.frame(individual=1:10, sectoral_data[inds, c("sector", "avg_wage")])
    individual sector avg_wage
1            1      a      400
1.1          2      a      400
1.2          3      a      400
4            4      d     1000
2            5      b      600
4.1          6      d     1000
1.3          7      a      400
4.2          8      d     1000
2.1          9      b      600
1.4         10      a      400
```

This is one way of doing it, but seems quite simple and direct.